# Upgrading Eclipse for Android - Having Problems

Tags: eclipse

I updated the Android Software to the latest and greatest, and it told me I need to update Eclipse to Helios or newer. So, I upgraded to Indigo, and now I'm getting the following message on startup of eclipse and can't move ahead with upgrading and getting back to work...

[image: eclipse starting issue]
<sub>(source: [pelepublications.com](http://pelepublications.com/eclipse_issue.png))</sub>

I'm concerned about moving the eclipse to a different folder b/c I don't know much about eclipse prefs and if it'll cause me problems (a need to update prefs that assume the default location) and if it needs to be in the Java/IDE folder. (I also suspect that shouldn't be the problem.)

I tried creating a batch file with the following content to pass in the argument they recommend, and it doesn't change the error.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\IDE\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -vmargs -Dosgi.locking=none
```

I also tried to change the eclipse.ini folder which now has the following contents - note the last line (this didn't help either)

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dosgi.locking=none
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong / how I can fix this problem? I need to get back to work...

I'm running eclipse on Windows 7

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think Windows 7 does not allow applications to write to the Program Files folder unless you run as administrator; I believe that's why you're seeing this message - Eclipse can't create a lock file where you have it installed.

Eclipse doesn't care where it is "installed" (really it's just unzipped); it does not put things in your windows registry or anything like that, so you can move it around at will. Your workspace(s) and projects are where the important stuff is stored.